# How pull web statistics using google analytics api through php client

Tags: php, google-app-engine, web, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

How do I retrieve `Google Analytics` data through the `Google Analytics API` using `PHP`?

Is it possible to get a page wise status through API?

I am working with a website having 30K pages and I need to create a dashboard showing page wise statistics for corresponding user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get the stats you are talking about though the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) using PHP.

There is a client library for php that I recommend it can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Because you will only be accessing your own data I recommend you go with a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) for authentication.

Simple example:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';

/************************************************
  The following 3 values an befound in the setting
  for the application you created on  Google 
  Developers console.
  The Key file should be placed in a location
  that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
  web root.

  In order to access your GA account you must
  Add the Email address as a user at the 
  ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin. 
 ************************************************/
$client_id = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$Email_address = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '629751513db09cd21a941399389f33e5abd633c9-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

// seproate additional scopes with a comma
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $Email_address,
    array($scopes),
    $key
    );

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);  
$accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

//calulating start date
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));

//Adding Dimensions
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType');
// requesting the data
$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:78110423", $date->format('Y-m-d'),  date("Y-m-d"), "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );


?><html>
<?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . " - ".date("Y-m-d"). "\n";?>
<table>
<tr>
<?php
//Printing column headers
foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){  
    print "<td>".$header['name']."</td>";   
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
//printing each row.
foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {    
    print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";  
}

//printing the total number of rows
?>
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>
</table>
</html>
<?php

?>
```

I you can find a tutorial for that code at [Google Service account php](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/)